# Texture/material mapping changes from viewport to render (p)

Tags: texturing, game-engine, materials

I am making a room in the blender game engine. I created corner, side and middle pieces. With linked copies of those pieces I assembled a room. The floors in the corner, side and middle pieces are exactly the same texture and material (seamless tiles image file) and in the viewport the floor of all pieces looks exactly the same. However, when I go into game mode ('p') suddenly the floor texture of the middle pieces shifts a little. How is this possible? Since they all use the same material and they are linked copies, the floor should look the same in all pieces right? GLSL is enabled. 
In response to Monster's comment, I hereby add images: 
Picture of Viewport: http://s1180.photobucket.com/user/knyntje/media/Work-related/game_mode_zpsabit55gz.jpg.html and of game mode: http://s1180.photobucket.com/user/knyntje/media/Work-related/3Dviewport_zpszy8j3ue0.jpg.html
Best, Nynke

Comment: An image of your setup and the effect you get would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for the images. Now I can see the shifting. Is the Texture/Mapping(Coordinates set to UV?

Comment: Hi, no for all three types of pieces (the corner, side and middle pieces) the setting is generated and I scaled the texture to 1.67. You can see in these images that the settings for the corner pieces and middle pieces are equal. The middle pieces are the ones that have the shifted texture. Corner: http://s1180.photobucket.com/user/knyntje/media/Work-related/corner_pieces_zpsgnjq2eu9.png.html?sort=3&o=0. Middle pieces: http://s1180.photobucket.com/user/knyntje/media/Work-related/middle_parts_zpsiip8kbtk.png.html?sort=3&o=1 As also visible in the images, all of similar type are linked copies.

Comment: I'm thinking you have scaled the floor piece that moves, check that it has a scale of 1.0 - Ctrl-A->Scale to apply the scale and set it to 1.0.

Comment: All types of pieces (corner, middle and side pieces) are scaled at 1.5... so that can also not explain the difference between the middle and other pieces....

Answer (score 1):

In response to Monster's comment I have tweaked some settings regarding UV. I found out that when I unwrapped the floors of all three types of pieces and I set the texture coordinate to UV that it looks the same for all floorpieces and also the same in the 3D view and the rendered view. 
Why it only went wrong with 1 type I still do not know (because I had not unwrapped any of the pieces earlier) but luckily the problem is solved now.